# OPTIONS request while adding Authorization header

Tags: ajax, header

Here's my problem, I'm trying to add the following Header to my GET ajax request :

```
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXX
```

So I wrote this :

```
    function() {
        var storage = window.localStorage;
        var currentUsername = storage.getItem("username");
        var currentPassword = storage.getItem("password");
        var auth = makeBasicAuth(currentUsername, currentPassword);
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", auth );
            }
        });
```

I already have check the value of *auth* which is correct. And when I try to send my request, I get that :

```
OPTIONS <myurl> Error 401
```

Here are the headers of the request and of its answer :

**Request :**

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-He...    authorization
Access-Control-Request-Me...    GET
Connection  keep-alive
Host    <myhost>
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
```

**Answer :**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    *
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Access-Control-Max-Age  3628800
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  440
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 23 Jul 2013 13:00:58 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=03A48D00EA04DE16396824E804E914AC; Path=/...
Vary    Accept-Encoding
WWW-Authenticate    Basic realm="Name Of Your Realm"
```

Note : I get this result whatever is the header I try to add.
Where is the problem ?

Thanks ^^.

Comment: Is your web server configured to accept the HTTP verb `options`?

Comment: I've just asked the person who is in charge of this server, I'm waiting for his answer.